# Should I use a Use Case even though it only acts as a middle-man to the Interface Adapter?

Tags: architecture, software-design, clean-architecture

I'm using Clean Architecture in my project. Now for instance I have an Interface Adapter like so:

```
protocol UserRepositoryInterface {
    func getSingle(id: String) -> Single<User?>
    func getAll() -> Single<[User]>
}

class UserRepositoryAdapter: UserRepositoryInterface {
    private let api: ApiService
    private let mapper: UserMapper
    init(api: ApiService,
         mapper: UserMapper) {
        self.api = api
        self.mapper = mapper
    }

    func getSingle(id: String) -> Single<User?> {
        return getAll()
            .map { $0.first(where: { $0.id == id }) }
    }

    func getAll() -> Single<[User]> {
        return api
            .getUserList()
            .compactMap { [weak self] in self?.mapper.map(from: $0) }
    }
}
```

And a simple Use Case like this:

```
protocol GetAllUsers {
    func get() -> Single<[User]>
}

class GetAllUsersUseCase {
    private let userRepo: UserRepositoryInterface
    init(userRepo: UserRepositoryInterface) {
        self.userRepo = userRepo
    }

    func get() -> Single<[User]> {
        return userRepo.getAll()
    }
}
```

The code is in Swift, but it can be in any other languages such as C#, C++, Java, Kotlin, etc. The question is still the same. Judging from the code, the `GetAllUsersUseCase` is just acting as a middle man between the `InterfaceAdapter` and `ViewModel`. Should I even use it because it is doing nothing else and should be considered a smell? Shouldn't the `ViewModel` use the `UserRepositoryInterface` directly? However, I've read this on https://refactoring.guru/smells/middle-man:

> When to Ignore
>
> Don’t delete middle man that have been created for a reason:
>
> 1. A middle man may have been added to avoid interclass dependencies.
> 2. Some design patterns create middle man on purpose (such as Proxy or
>    Decorator).

Is this just one of the instances where we can tolerate the code smell like mentioned above (and thus I should still use the Use Case)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A use-case in CA in an implementation of the "input port" concept. Jumping from view model straight to domain repository interface would be as if you declare you want to pass user request to repository as is, therefore applying business validations inside repository.

Such validations should, of course, not take place in infrastructure layer. Instead, they should occur inside domain entities, which should be managed inside application layer (and not inside presentation layer); or inside those exact objects managing mentioned domain entities, namely application services or use-cases.

Another reason for sticking to use-case objects is the possibility you would need to enrich flow of getting all users. Although currently requirements can be simple, at some point in the future it might be necessary to, for example, filter out some users based on some criteria. Such scaling is best met when you have a use-case object where you can, for example, add a `SelectedUsers` specification and pass it to repository method. Specifications are not to exist in view model, but in application layer.

Comment: That's a pretty detailed answer. Thanks. However, what I had in mind about this is the YAGNI principle. My logic is that when there is no other logic that needs to be handled in a Use Case (eg. validation, data transformation, etc), should we still use that middle-man UseCase or not? For me, I would have used the InterfaceAdapter itself and when the additional logic is needed, then we create the UseCase, not before. Or should we just create it in advance even though we might not have other logic in it in the future?

Comment: YAGNI encourages refactoring skills and agile work, however it does not mean we cannot think ahead of a beneficial top-level design. Consider the small price you pay for writing a "thin" use-case object, against the risk of an application becoming messy for having one developer skipped writing the middleman, drawing the way for new developers with little knowledge of CA to add business logic straight to interface adapter. So I would say no to filter-based repositories and sophisticated design patterns if not required at the moment, but yes to CA (even with some thin use cases).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks again.